# WebADF 931 to 10 migration issues

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-web-adf

I am in process of migating a web ADF 931 application to WEBADF 10. The application uses some samples from ESRI forum/samples. I am curious if there are versions of these files available within WebADF 10 environment. it seems like these are designed to work with 931 web controls. Appreciate any feedback. Thanks Jay

## Referenced libraries:

<%@ Register Assembly="gridResults, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4117b0729e6ae73a" Namespace="esri_samples" TagPrefix="esri_samples" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="PrintTask_VBNet, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2a7e7966c16048d7" Namespace="PrintTask_VBNet" TagPrefix="printTaskVB" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="WorldViewSolutions.ArcGISServer.WebControls.FeatureSearch"
Namespace="WorldViewSolutions.ArcGISServer.WebControls.FeatureSearch" TagPrefix="wvs2" %>

## These are the errors I am getting:

Unable to create type 'esri_samples:gridResults'. Could not load file or assembly 'ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls, Version=9.3.1.3000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to create type 'wvs2:FeatureSearchTask'. Could not load file or assembly 'ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls, Version=9.3.1.3000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to create type 'oat:OpenAttributeTableTask'. Could not load file or assembly 'ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls, Version=9.3.1.3000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Did you install the ArcGIS ADF for version 10?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've installed 10. update the references to use the 10 version.

Change the File and Assembly version then rebuild the solution.
at the top of the aspx page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="gridResults, Version=1.3.1.33, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xx" Namespace="esri_samples" TagPrefix="esri_samples" %>
```

in the web.config:

```
<add assembly="gridResults, Version=1.3.1.33, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xx"/>
```

Then try recompiling.

Comment: Yes, he will need the source projects from the ESRI samples, then update all of the references to the 10 libraries, recompile and then merge into his code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is why everyone cringes when ESRI puts out a new version of their software.  At least with version 10, they are allowing us to set the "Specific Version" property to False.  Maybe it won't be so bad when v. 10.1 is released.

If these are your programs - or you have the source code, you will need to migrate the project to use v. 10 assemblies.

If you know who the author is or can find the download site, you can see if the author has provided (or will provide) an update for version 10.

I've never tried this, but you could try copying the 9.3.1 assemblies to the new computer and see if your application will find them.

Good Luck

Comment: "Specific version" property for a VS reference has nothing to do with assembly resolution at runtime. It only affects reference resolution for your VS project, not for the resulting compiled assembly.

Comment: As for 10 to 10.1 migration, expect more trouble since ESRI stopped distributing policy files with their assemblies. You will need to configure assembly redirects in your application configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

You will also find the long-term issue of ESRI moving away from the ADFs to be a bigger issue. There drive for the JSAPI and the Flex/Silverlight APIs have really pushed vendors who backed the ADF into the corner.

At V10.1 you will see much of the ADF changing as 10.1 will be 64bit only, no longer 32bit which much of the older ArcObjects/COM model use. So you can expect if there is ADF support there that major revisions will be needed to support your codebase.